# How do I remove the change keyboard button in android 11?

Tags: keyboard

I keep hitting it instead of the spacebar and I want to remove it from the keyboard if I can. Circled in the photo. [image]

Comment: This looks like the standard GBoard keyboard. As Android allows you to install other keyboard apps you can search for a keyboard that has a different layout.